# Variable initialising and constructors

Tags: c++, variables, constructor, initialization

I am currently taking a c++ course and trying to get a deep understanding of the whole thing.
I came up with some theories, it would be great if somebody could confirm them:

Every variable (local,global,staic,member and non-member) is guaranteed to have its ctor called before first use

The ctors of primitives like int are essentially no-ops, so we have explicitly assign a value, there is no default zero value.

the following classes are semantically the same (and should generate identical code)

```
class A 
{ 
  int n; 
};
```

and

```
class A 
{
  int n;
 public:
  A() : n() {}
};
```

and

```
class A 
{
  int n;
 public:
  A() { n = int(); }
};
```

The variable n is in every case still uninitialized.

EDIT:

It seem that I absolutetly underestimated the complexity of this subject, most of my assumptions were wrong. Now Iam still trying to find out the basic rules of object initialisation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find [this](http://unixjunkie.blogspot.com/2009/05/c-new-foo-vs-new-foo.html) interesting.

> The difference between new Foo and new
>   Foo() is that former will be
>   uninitialized and the latter will be
>   default initialized (to zero) when Foo
>   is a POD type. So, when not using the
>   form with the parens, the member "a"
>   can contain garbage, but with the
>   parens "a" will always be initialized
>   to 0.

Comment: I find this statement hard to believe. class Bar { int n; } is a POD because it's implicitly-defined ctor is /trivial/ (formal term from ISO). Yet, it exists, and both `new Bar;` and `new Bar()` call it. In neither case will Bar::Bar() initialize Bar::n

Comment: "class B {int n;};" is *not* a POD because it contains a private non-static member 'n'.  However, if it was defined as "class B { public: int n; };" then it would be a POD, and so 'n' will be value-initialized when you do "new Bar()".

Comment: Is it even possible for a newbie to fully understand this subject? There seem to be so many rules and exceptions :-(

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid you are wrong. When you say:

```
int n = int();
```

Then n (and all other POD types) will zero initialised.

Also, make sure that you are very clear in your mind about the difference between initialisation and assignment - this is quite important in C++:

```
int n = int();    // initialisation
n = 0;            // assignment
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the variable is only left uninitialised in the first case.

For a member that is a class with a user-defined constructor, the situation is simple: a constructor is always called.

Built-in types (and 'plain old data' structs) may be left uninitialised, as in your first example. Although they don't have user-supplied constructors, using the construction syntax (your other two examples) initialises them to zero.

The reason for this slightly tricky rule is to avoid undue overhead; for example if you defined:

```
struct S
{
   int array[1024*1024];
};
```

with the intention of only assigning values as you needed them, you wouldn't want the compiler to whitewash 4Mb of memory with zeroes whenever you construct one.

Comment: This is hillarious, it is much more complicated than I thought. If I create an empty ctor A(){}, then the variable n is initialized! I always thought that when you have an empty ctor it is the same as having no ctor (which implicity will create a default ctor), so my 1st and 4rd classes should be identical, but they aren't.

Comment: That sounds wrong. Are you using an old version of GCC? Also, you should state where you are creating the instance of A: I'm assuming on the stack or heap. If it's a static object, the members will be initialised to zero before the constructor is called (this is called 'value initialisation', if you want to Google for it).

Answer (score 1):

```
class A 
{ 
   int n; 
};
```

Only memory is allocated, no initialization done for `n`.

---

```
class A 
{
  int n;
 public:
  A() : n() {}
};
```

Here `n` is initialized with 0.

---

```
class A 
{
  int n;
 public:
  A() { n = int(); }
};
```

Here `n` is first constructed (without any default value),
then *`int()`* causes a temp int to be created with value 0
Which is then assigned to `n`;

Comment: Very strange. I was sure that I once had the second version with A():n(){} in a project of mine and it caused n not to be initialized. I used GCC though. Could this be compiler dependent?

Comment: @codymanix. No this is standard behavior. Though I believe in the first version of the standard this was not specified because who would do such a thing!!! So your observations may be true for a very old compiler.